# Where can I ask a theoretical-hardware question about near future CMOS microprocessors?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Hello

Where can I ask a teoretical-hardware question about near future CMOS microprocessors?

There was an attempt to ask it on StackOverFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206907/mflops-per-watt-what-is-the-limit-closed but it was closed.

Also, I wonder to know where to ask other VLSI-related questions (about microprocessor internals, hardware design, opencores, verilog coding, etc), like such: [multiplication in multicycle datapath write from stratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062741/multiplication-in-multicycle-datapath-write-from-stratch) and [Verilog to GDSII compiler (open-source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180596/verilog-to-gdsii-compiler-open-source)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are some numbers about pJ (picojoules) per FLOPS (actually per fused multiply-add with double precision) here: [GPUS AND THE FUTURE OF PARALLEL COMPUTING](http://www.davidglasco.com/Papers/ieee-micro.pdf), Keckler 2011 (www.davidglasco.com/Papers/ieee-micro.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The information theoretical limit is a topic that span the confluence between [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and full on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). But subjects have their sites in beta, though I would recommend that you read Feynman on the Theory of Computation first.

If you care about a "near future" engineering limit there does not appear to be an good site in the League of Justice. [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) might be the best match, but it is a bit of a stretch and I'd be surprised if you get a good answer..